# MVC 5, Database migration

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to MVC5 
I've this error when i have executed the command 
**-update-database:**
I've three tables, when i did execute the command two among them were populated, and the third one were not.

1. **PM> Update-Database**
2. Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied
   to the target database. No pending explicit migrations. Running Seed
   method.
3. at
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
   command)

**Sequence contains no matching element**

Comment: Looks like something went wrong in your Seed() code. Show that code and indicate where it failed. Also, run `update-database -Verbose` as suggested to get more information.

Comment: I will try to post the code here later.